# Binding Parameter PDO prepared Statement

Tags: php, pdo

I really dont know why i am having this error even after binding parameters

```
 SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

Here is my function

```
    public function get_no_records($param){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username = :value";
    $this->query = $query;
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value',$param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row_num = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($row_num > 0){
        $this->total_rec = $row_num;
        return $row_num;
    }
}
```

The function is part of a pagination class.This is the class

```
<?php
class Paginator{
private $db;
public $page_no;//current page
public $limit;//record_per page
public $row_start;
public $total_rec;
public $query;

function __construct($con){
    $this->db = $con;
}
//get total no of records

    public function get_no_records($param){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username = :value";
    $this->query = $query;
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value',$param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row_num = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($row_num > 0){
        $this->total_rec = $row_num;
        return $row_num;
    }
}
public function get_data($limit,$page_no){
    try {
        $this->limit = $limit;
        $this->page_no = $page_no;
        if($this->limit == "all"){
            $query = $this->query;
        }
        else{
            $this->row_start = (($this->page_no-1) * $this->limit);
            $query = $this->query . " LIMIT ". $this->row_start . "," . $this->limit;
        }
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            //create an array to hold record
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        $result = new stdClass();
        $result->page_no = $this->page_no;
        $result->limit = $this->limit;
        $result->total_rec = $this->total_rec;
        $result->data = $results;
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
public function create_links($links,$list_class){
    if($this->limit == 'all'){
        return '';
    }
    $last = ceil($this->total_rec/$this->limit);
    $start = (($this->page_no - $links) > 0) ? $this->page_no - $links : 1;
    $end = (($this->page_no + $links) < $last) ? $this->page_no + $links : $last;
    $html = '<ul class="' . $list_class . '">';
    $class = ($this->page_no == 1) ? "disabled" : "";
    $previous_page = ($this->page_no == 1) ?
    '<a href= ""><li class="' . $class . '">&laquo;</a></li>' :
    '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=' . ($this->page_no-1) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';
    $html .= $previous_page;
    if($start > 1){
        $html .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=1">1</a></li>';
        $html .= '<li class="disabled"><span>....</span></li>'; 
    }
    for($i = $start;$i<=$end;$i++){
        $class = ($this->page_no == $i)? "active" : "";
        $html .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=' . $i .'">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }
    if( $end < $last){
        $html .= '<li class="disabled"><span>....</span></li>';
        $html .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=' . $last . '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
    }
    $class = ($this->page_no == $last)? "disabled" : "";

    $next_page = ( $this->page_no == $last)?
    '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="">&raquo;</a></li>':
    '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=' . ($this->page_no + 1) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';
    $html .= $next_page;
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

}
?>

Comment: what type is `$param` ? And maybe consider stating the type explicitly

Comment: its is  string..

Comment: @JRsz av tried that..My question has been updated with the class the function is contained in

Comment: @RyanVincent i dont understand you

Comment: I don't think the sql error is from the `get_no_records` function but from the `get_data` function?

Comment: Ill try that now

Comment: It still not working, the problem is binding parameters

Comment: It's my code.. When I var_dump on $stmt after execution , it's still had :value which means it was not bounded and I don't know why

Comment: Please are you on Facebook or WhatsApp

Comment: 1. get rid of ALL try and catch operators. 2. Edit your question and add the FULL error message you will get. 3. Highlight the line in your code the error message is pointing at.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you all. I have gotten where the error is coming from, its the get_data(),since that function also contains a the query,a value has to be binded as well.Here is my new code.

```
<?php
class Paginator{
private $db;
public $page_no;//current page
public $limit;//record_per page
public $row_start;
public $total_rec;
public $query;

function __construct($con){
    $this->db = $con;
}
//get total no of records
public function get_no_records($query,$value){
    $this->query = $query;
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value',$value);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row_num = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($row_num > 0){
        $this->total_rec = $row_num;
        return $row_num;
    }
}
public function get_data($limit,$page_no,$value){
    try {
        $this->limit = $limit;
        $this->page_no = $page_no;
        if($this->limit == "all"){
            $query = $this->query;
        }
        else{
            $this->row_start = (($this->page_no-1) * $this->limit);
            $query = $this->query . " LIMIT ". $this->row_start . "," . $this->limit;
        }
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam('value',$value);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            //create an array to hold record
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        if(empty($results)){
            return;
        }
        $result = new stdClass();
        $result->page_no = $this->page_no;
        $result->limit = $this->limit;
        $result->total_rec = $this->total_rec;
        $result->data = $results;
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
public function create_links($links,$list_class){
    if($this->limit == 'all'){
        return '';
    }
    $last = ceil($this->total_rec/$this->limit);
    $start = (($this->page_no - $links) > 0) ? $this->page_no - $links : 1;
    $end = (($this->page_no + $links) < $last) ? $this->page_no + $links : $last;
    $html = '<ul class="' . $list_class . '">';
    $class = ($this->page_no == 1) ? "disabled" : "";
    $previous_page = ($this->page_no == 1) ?
    '<a href= ""><li class="' . $class . '">&laquo;</a></li>' :
    '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=' . ($this->page_no-1) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';
    $html .= $previous_page;
    if($start > 1){
        $html .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=1">1</a></li>';
        $html .= '<li class="disabled"><span>....</span></li>'; 
    }
    for($i = $start;$i<=$end;$i++){
        $class = ($this->page_no == $i)? "active" : "";
        $html .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=' . $i .'">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }
    if( $end < $last){
        $html .= '<li class="disabled"><span>....</span></li>';
        $html .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=' . $last . '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
    }
    $class = ($this->page_no == $last)? "disabled" : "";

    $next_page = ( $this->page_no == $last)?
    '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="">&raquo;</a></li>':
    '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->limit . '&page_no=' . ($this->page_no + 1) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';
    $html .= $next_page;
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
}
?>
```

The query in the get_data() has a parameter of $value  bounded now,before execution of the query.

Comment: Glad you debugged and fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not use bind param but the execute statement only.

```
public function get_no_records($param)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username = :my_value;";
    $this->query = $query; //What use do I have?
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute(array(':my_value' => $param));

    $row_num = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($row_num > 0)
    {
        $this->total_rec = $row_num;
        return $row_num;
    }

    return 0; //Added so the function always has a return value
}
```

The binding of `':value'` is done by creating an associative array that is only used as a parameter for the execute function.

Comment: Thanks. But i still have same result, get_no_records($param) is in a class and i have public variable within the class where i assign the query to

Comment: Do you get the exact same error? And are all tables and columns present in the database?

Comment: I got exactly same error , all tables and columns are present

Comment: ok, so lets check everything step by step. Can you execute simple querys in the very function you are having problems with? Querys like `SELECT * FROM users_tbl;` ?

Comment: ok Thanks.But in that case, i have to comment the binparam out and pass no argument to the method

Comment: correct, only call execute without any input params and no bindParams

Comment: I did that and got this error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 `

Comment: what query did you use?

Comment: I used `SELECT * FROM users_tbl`

Comment: I just used `SELECT * FROM users_tbl;` and it executed without error

Comment: ok, have you tried my modified answer with the `;` at the end of the query?

Comment: The problem has to do with binding parameters and if i don't bind, my code may be vulnerable to SQl injection

Comment: Hm, I see your point. It just came to my mind that `value` is a reserved word in MySQL. Maybe it works if you use something different, like `my_value`. See my updated answer. And do not forget the `;` at the end of the query ;)

Comment: Thanks alot..But still same error..Please are you on facebook

Comment: ok, let me setup a test environment by myself and I try to check your code. But this could take a few minutes. No, I do not have facebook. But I am currently on https://webchat.quakenet.org/ in the channel SO_PHP_PDO

Comment: I just joined the chat

Comment: Please, do not post an irrelevant story instead of an answer.